# Strongly polynomial time algorithm for shortest convex combination

Tags: time-complexity, linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hull

Problem: Let $S$ be a finite set of vectors. Let $C$ be their [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). Compute $\operatorname{argmin}_{x \in C} \|x\|$.

Reference 1 gives an algorithm for this problem that is finite-time (Section 2). However, its worst-case time complexity is not given.

Reference 2 gives another algorithm for this problem, but it is not finite-time (Theorem 2).

Is there a [strongly polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time) algorithm for this problem?

References:

1. *[Algorithm for a least-distance programming problem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0121249)*. Philip Wolfe. Mathematical Programming Studies. Volume 1, March 1974, Pages 190-205.
2. *[An algorithm for finding the shortest element of a polyhedral set with application to Lagrangian duality](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X78901804)*. Mokhtar S Bazaraa, Jamie J Goode, Ronald L Rardin. Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications. Volume 65, Issue 2, September 1978, Pages 278-288.

Comment: Is there a strongly poly-time reduction from general LP to this problem? (This would mean a strongly poly-time algorithm is not known, right?)  Given an arbitrary feasibility LP $Ax=b; x \ge 0$, reduce it to $Ax = b; x \ge 0, \sum_i x_i \le N$ for some very large $N$, then (by adding a slack variable and scaling) put in form $Ax = b; x \ge 0; \sum_i x_i = 1$, then reduce this to $A' x = 0; x \ge 0; \sum_i x_i = 1$ for appropriate $A$.  The latter feasibility question is just whether the convex hull of the columns of $A'$ contains the origin, i.e., whether the answer to your question is zero.

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3188745.3188820 shows that general LP reduces in strongly poly time to minimum norm point in a simplex. Also has other related results. You can also see slides of a talk https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/9999/presentation-3.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known via a [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3188745.3188820) of De Loera, Haddock and Rademacher that a strongly polynomial time algorithm for finding a minimum norm point in a simplex implies a strongly polynomial time algorithm for general LP. We do not know whether LP has a strongly poly time algorithm - this is a fundamental open problem in optimization.

Comment: Some of Vavasis's papers may also be relevant. First is showing that quadratic programming is in NP. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002001909090100C Second is on weakly polynomial time algorithms for finding some local optima. https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/epdf/10.1142/9789814354363_0022

Comment: In the other direction, does this also reduce to LP?